# How to find a directory in vs code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, command

Hi I am taking a dart programming course on udemy and we are currently making a command line app. I pressed CTRL + C to exit a endless loop and now there is no text on the line of the terminal where previously it showed my current location. How do I get back to this from a terminal that has a blank flashing line.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close the terminal by clicking my "terminate" button on the right upper corner and close the vs code also.

After that navigate to the folder where you have created your dart project. Right Click in the folder and open with vs code.

Now When you open terminal again by pressing ctrl + `, terminal will be open in your current project showing the current folder path.